# Tkinter Python, is it possible to lock a Frame's size despite the widget within. Specifially Text widgets

Tags: python, tkinter, text, frame, pack

I am trying to size some Frames and then pack Text widgets into them. Maybe I am missing something.
Firstly is there a proper way to have the Text widget "inherit" its size from the Frame?
I have tried this

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

f = tk.Frame(width=100, height=50, relief="raised", borderwidth=2)
f.pack()

t = tk.Text(master=f)
t.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

and the Text's default size overwrites the Frame's size. So I tried to  change it to

```
...
t = tk.Text(master=f, width=100, height=50)
...
```

and the size is wildly different, which I realize is because the height and width for Text is the character size. So I did some math and got:

```
...
t = tk.Text(master=f, width=12, height=6)
...
```

So my real question is, is there a way to pack Text into a Frame and set its size via pixels rather than character? Or to lock the size of the Frame regardless of the Text within?
For my purposes I only ever need one widget in the Frame for the most part, but essentially what I'd like to be able to do it size a bunch of Frames and pack widgets into them, maybe their is a better way to do this. Any thoughts are appreciated

Answer (score 1):

> So my real question is, is there a way to pack Text into a Frame and set its size via pixels rather than character?

No, you cannot set the size of the text widget in pixels. However, you tell it to fill the frame, and then tell the frame not to let the children determine its size. Since you're using `pack`, you would use `pack_propagate`. This will allow you to set the size of the frame in pixels.

```
f = tk.Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
t = tk.Text(f)
f.pack_propagate(False)
t.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

Comment: Hey this is great, it totally works, but I messed up in my question, I am using place. Is there some equivalent of place propagate, that I can use to place the Frame without it being resized?

Comment: @fudgeBreadstein: `place` doesn’t have the same behavior as `grid` and `pack`. With `place` you can directly set the size of the widget being placed using 5he `width`, `relwidth`, `height` and `relheight` options.